# Visual studio 2015 Cordova Android Error with device

Tags: android, angularjs, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am using 2015 CTP 6. I have correct JAVA_HOME and all other variables set. Here is my env.

angularjs 1.3.14

jQuery 1.8.0

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40

ADT_HOME = C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

ANT_HOME =C:\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin\apache-ant-1.9.4

Node.js verion 0.12.2

Everything works fine in Ripple emulator.

I get this error while deploying to device. Device is connected, unlock.

Command failed with exit code 1
------------ Detail error ----------

> 1> 
>   C:\sourcecode\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:1
>   (TaskId:11)
>
> 1>  (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
>   C:\sourcecode\Ch (TaskId:11)
>
> 1>                                                                  ^
>   (TaskId:11)
>
> 1>  SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL (TaskId:11)
>
> 1>      at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16) (TaskId:11)
>
> 1>      at Module._compile (module.js:443:25) (TaskId:11)
>
> (C:\sourcecode\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\lib\exec.js:23:15)
>   (TaskId:11)
>
> 1>      at Module._compile (module.js:460:26) (TaskId:11)
>
> 1>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>   (TaskId:11)
>
> 1>  Command finished with error code 1: 
>   C:\sourcecode\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat
>   --debug,--ant, (TaskId:11)
>
> 1>MDAVSCLI : error :
>
> C:\sourcecode\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command
>   failed with exit code 1

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be a invalid/hidden character in your project code files. Have you tried sanitizing it as described [here](http://www.stramaxon.com/2013/01/hidden-characters-error-javascript.html)?